Sending a dashboard by email to users external
I would like to send a dashboard periodically with filter choices depending on the recipient
Currently, I know how to send reports in Excel files
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

List< Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> lstAttachment = new List< Messaging.EmailFileAttachment>();
String instanceName = System.URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm();

string url=instanceName+'/servlet/PrintableViewDownloadServlet?isdtp=p1&reportId='+idRapport+'&details=no';
ApexPages.PageReference report = new ApexPages.PageReference(url);

Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();

 attachment.setFileName('report.xls');
 attachment.setBody(report.getContent());
 attachment.setContentType('application/vnd.ms-excel'); // or text/csv
 lstAttachment.add(attachment);

I tested with
string url=instanceName+'/servlet/PrintableViewDownloadServlet?isdtp=p1&dashboardId='+idReport;

But page not found
I also tested with
Http client = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
request.setEndPoint(System.URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm() + '/analytics/download/report/00Oxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pdf');
request.setMethod('GET');
HttpResponse response = client.send(request);

But the attached file is invalid
(I don't know how to check if my dashboard is Analytics)
Do you have any idea?
PS: We would have about 150 different filter values, if possible a preselection of filters would be ideal in order to avoid creating 150 dashboards

This question is similar to: Store Lightning Dashboard as PNG in Files. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

^^^ translation: you have to screen-scrape. While doing so might be technically possible with some combination of front-end (e.g. LWC) and Apex all running in a non-interactive mode, you're better off implementing this from a non-Apex client.

It would be better to use an analytics tool like Tableau or PowerBI so the external users can view the dashboards directly.  If you're forced to use email + Excel, then a doc gen tool like Conga or Apsona is best to merge data into an Excel template.

Thanks for yours responses ! I think PowerBi will be y solution !
